# $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{n \ge 1} a_{n, k} = \sup_{n \ge 1} \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n,k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

This is important for me and somehow I can't think straight now so I need some help.

Suppose $a_{n,k}$ is a real double sequence and it is bounded. Is it possible to prove the claim $$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{n \ge 1} a_{n, k} = \sup_{n \ge 1} \lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n,k}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_{n,k}=1$ if $k\leq n$, $a_{n,k}=0$ if $k>n$. Then
$$ \sup_{n\geq 1}\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n,k}=\sup_{n\geq 1}0=0 $$
while
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty}\sup_{n\geq 1}a_{n,k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}1=1 $$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we can list the elements of $a_{n,k}$ in a set called $\Delta$ = {$a_{1,0} \dots a_{n,k} $} . This sequence is bounded so is the set of it's elements ,so $\Delta$ has an upper bound $sup$ $a_{n,k}$.Lets distinguish 3 cases.

**$ a\cdot$) $a_{n,k}$ is a constant sequence.**

The set $\Delta$ is a singleton denoted by {$a_{n',k'}$} and $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ = $a_{n',k'}$ so the above equality holds.

**$ b\cdot$) $a_{n,k}$ is an increasing sequence.**

$a_{n,k}$ converges.

Arranging the set $\Delta$ in ascending order {$a_{n'',k''} \dots a_{n',k'}$} ,$sup$ $\Delta$ is $a_{n',k'}$ so $\lim_{k\to\infty}$$sup$ $a_{n,k}$= $a_{n',k'}$

From the property of the upper bound. $$supa_{n,k}-\epsilon \le a_{n,k} \le supa_{n,k}$$

$$-\epsilon \le a_{n,k}-supa_{n,k} \le 0 \le \epsilon$$

$$\mid a_{n,k}-supa_{n,k}\mid \le \epsilon$$

This shows that $sup$ $a_{n,k}$ is the limit of the sequence, applying the supremum shows the equality.

**$ c\cdot$) $a_{n,k}$ is a decreasing sequence.**

$a_{n,k}$ converges.

Arranging the set $\Delta$ in ascending order {$a_{n'',k''} \dots a_{n',k'}$} ,$sup$ $\Delta$ is $a_{n',k'}$ so $\lim_{k\to\infty}$$sup$ $a_{n,k}$= $a_{n',k'}$

From the property of the lower bound. $$infa_{n,k}\le a_{n,k} \le infa_{n,k}+\epsilon$$

$$-\epsilon \le 0\le a_{n,k}-infa_{n,k} \le \epsilon$$

$$\mid a_{n,k}-infa_{n,k}\mid \le \epsilon$$

This shows that $inf$ $a_{n,k}$ is the limit of the sequence, applying the supremum **doesn't show** the equality.